# how to find image inside a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on an html page where i have div element and also a inner div element. In the inner div element there is a image element. The main and inner div are 2 in numbers.

```
<div class="owl-stage-outer">

<div class="owl-item" style="width: 1903px;"><div class="header-single-slider">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="assets/img/sliders/slider01.jpg" alt="">
                        <figcaption>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="container inner-content text-left">
                                    <h1 style="display: block;" class="fadeInUp animated">We Build Your<br><span>Business</span> IDEA</h1>
                                    <p style="display: block;" class="fadeInDown animated">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available but the majority have suffered injected humour dummy now.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="boxed-btn fadeInDown animated" style="display: inline-block;">Read More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div></div>

 <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 1903px;"><div class="header-single-slider">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="assets/img/sliders/slider02.jpg" alt="">
                        <figcaption>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="container inner-content text-left">
                                    <h1 style="display: block;" class="fadeInUp animated">We Build Your<br><span>Business</span> IDEA</h1>
                                    <p style="display: block;" class="fadeInDown animated">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available but the majority have suffered injected humour dummy now.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="boxed-btn fadeInDown animated" style="display: inline-block;">Read More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div></div>
</div>
```

Here the main div whose class is 'owl-item' is used 2 times and the inner div whose class is 'header-single-slider' is also used 2 times. When the program runs The main div whose class is 'owl-item', its class changes to 'owl-item acitve' means this class is active now and second div class remain as 'owl-item'. after some seconds the second div will becomes active and its class becomes'owl-item active' and first will remain inactive and its class will be 'owl-item'

I want to find the image src of that div whose class is 'owl-item active'. For this i used the following query:

```
alert($('.owl-item active').children('div').children("img").attr('src'));
```

But it is showing alert message as 'Undefined'. How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't select your `active` `owl-item` correctly.

You can simply use

```
$('.owl-item.active>div>figure>img').attr('src')
```

If you're sure you only have one `img` in your div, just use `'.owl-item.active img'` instead.

```js
console.log($('.owl-item.active>div>figure>img').attr('src'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-stage-outer">

  <div class="owl-item" style="width: 1903px;">
    <div class="header-single-slider">
      <figure>
        <img src="assets/img/sliders/slider01.jpg" alt="">
        <figcaption>
          <div class="content">
            <div class="container inner-content text-left">
              <h1 style="display: block;" class="fadeInUp animated">We Build Your<br><span>Business</span> IDEA</h1>
              <p style="display: block;" class="fadeInDown animated">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available but the majority have suffered injected humour dummy now.</p>
              <a href="#" class="boxed-btn fadeInDown animated" style="display: inline-block;">Read More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 1903px;">
    <div class="header-single-slider">
      <figure>
        <img src="assets/img/sliders/slider02.jpg" alt="">
        <figcaption>
          <div class="content">
            <div class="container inner-content text-left">
              <h1 style="display: block;" class="fadeInUp animated">We Build Your<br><span>Business</span> IDEA</h1>
              <p style="display: block;" class="fadeInDown animated">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available but the majority have suffered injected humour dummy now.</p>
              <a href="#" class="boxed-btn fadeInDown animated" style="display: inline-block;">Read More <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please help me to find out whether image src contains 1,2 or 3.

Comment: @SunnySandeep Ask another question and link it to me, I'll take a look.

Comment: i dont know how to link.

Comment: @SunnySandeep see my comment

Comment: Before asking another question, look for an answer on StackOverflow, your problem has already been asked many times. The answer should include `indexOf` or a `RegEx`

Answer (score 2):

You **forgot** a `.` before active

```
$('.owl-item.active img').attr('src')
```

Comment: and you forgot `. ` before `owl-item` :D

Comment: could you please help me to find out whether image src contains 1,2 or 3.

Comment: @SunnySandeep `var src= $('.owl-item.active img').attr('src') if(src.indexOf("1") != -1)`

Comment: @SunnySandeep tell me if it helps

Comment: plaese explain it you want if src=1 or 2 or 3 **OR** contain

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` method.

```
console.log($('.owl-item.active').find('figure>img').attr('src'));
```